# Fields referenced in query not found in input events Fields Expected: TIME Fields found: MESSAGEID Azure Stream Analytics Job

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics, mxchip

I just created an Azure Stream Analytics job and configured the Inputs and Outputs, and this Stream Analytics job is taking Azure IoT hub as the Input which receives the data from an Azure IoT Dev Kit MXChip. But I am getting an error in the Input job topology details as below.

```
[4:10:13 PM] Fields referenced in query not found in input events
Fields Expected: TIME
Fields found: MESSAGEID, HUMIDITY
Missing fields: TIME
```

[image]

Below is my query.

```
WITH BasicOutput AS 
(
SELECT    
    messageId,
    System.TIMESTAMP AS TIME,
    deviceId,
    temperature,
    humidity,
    pressure,
    pointInfo,
    IoTHub,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    PartitionId,    
    count(*) AS Count
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP By TIME
    GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(minute, 2), 
    messageId, 
    deviceId,
    temperature,
    humidity,
    pressure,
    pointInfo,
    IoTHub,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    PartitionId
)

SELECT * INTO SQLServerOutput FROM BasicOutput
SELECT * INTO AzureFunctionOutput FROM BasicOutput
```

Have you ever faced this issue? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some search in Google and find out this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/tumbling-window-azure-stream-analytics). After reading the same I updated my query as follows.

```
WITH BasicOutput AS 
(
SELECT    
    messageId,
    deviceId,
    temperature,
    humidity,
    pressure,
    pointInfo,
    IoTHub,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    PartitionId,    
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP By EventEnqueuedUtcTime
    GROUP BY TUMBLINGWINDOW(second, 2), 
    messageId, 
    deviceId,
    temperature,
    humidity,
    pressure,
    pointInfo,
    IoTHub,
    EventEnqueuedUtcTime,
    EventProcessedUtcTime,
    PartitionId
)

SELECT * INTO SQLServerOutput FROM BasicOutput
SELECT * INTO AzureFunctionOutput FROM BasicOutput
```

I removed the `System.TIMESTAMP AS TIME,` from my select and add `TIMESTAMP By EventEnqueuedUtcTime`. It started working after this change.